How to get Shape Geometry and all required fields for a Price calculation process?

I'm using the Model Derivative API for extracting Metadata and Geometry of a design, But here is the problem:

What we are trying to build is a website that provides different kind of materials and thicknesses For a CNC machine to cut. Users upload files (.DXF, .DWG, .STEP) then select material and thickness options.

We need to know how to calculate the total area of the shape and the total cut length if possible.

In a nutshell, We need the data that helps us calculate the price for a specific material.


Thanks

Get the metadata and properties of the parts and calculate using the base price. you can get this functionality in this sample: https://aps-cost-analysis.autodesk.io/

How is the price calculated ? based on what parameters, area or number of items or other criteria ?

you can check the code here: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-cost-analysis/blob/main/wwwroot/main.js#L92
This is just a sample with dummy prices. You can calculate based on volume or mass and multiply by unit price.
